# Extract uintptr from reflect.Value

Tags: pointers, go, interface, casting

## Given

```
// I know that behind SomeInterface can hide either int or a pointer to struct
// In the real code I only have v, not i
i := something.(SomeInterface)
v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
var p uintptr
if "i is a pointer to struct" {
    p = ???
}
```

1. I need some way to distinguish between pointers and values in this situation.
2. If `i` was a pointer to struct, I need to cast it to `uintptr`.

---

Something I discovered so far: the second member of the `(*reflect.Value).InterfaceData()` will be the pointer to the struct, in case it is a struct. I have no idea what it is in case it is not a struct.

Comment: Anything can fulfil the interface, even `int` or `string` or a pointer to a struct which isn't struct.

Comment: @kopiczko What are you trying to say?

Comment: @wvxvw: are you just asking how to check if the `reflect.Kind` of v is a pointer? Note that you cannot correctly store a pointer value in a `uintptr`

Comment: @wvxvw I said that regarding your statement: "I have no idea what it is in case it is not a struct."

Comment: @kopiczko OK, I see where the confusion is coming from now. I was referring to the second value returned by `InterfaceData()`. I think you are talking about whether different basic types can implement interfaces.

Comment: @JimB but `InterfaceData()` uses `uintptr` for storage. Can you elaborate on why isn't it possible to store the pointer as `uintptr`?

Comment: @wvxvw: because those are the rules of the language. A `uintptr` is an integer value, not a pointer, and won't be seen by the GC. if you need a generic pointer use [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer). The unsafe docs have more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Pointer](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Pointer) method to get the address of a struct as a uintpr:

```
var p uintptr
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && v.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    p = v.Pointer()
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/7j1ipklD3l)

This code assumes that `v` is the result of calling `reflect.ValueOf(i)` as shown in the question.  In this scenario, `v` represents `i`'s element, not `i`.  For example, if interface `i` contains an `int`, then `v.Kind()` is  `reflect.Int`, not `reflect.Interface`.

If `v` has an interface value, then drill down through the interface to get the uintptr:

```
if v.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
    v = v.Elem()
}
var p uintptr
if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && v.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    p = v.Pointer()
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/TLwwQVb5fI)

Comment: Let me check this first, but on the surface of it, in your second listing, `v = v.Elem()` will panic if the actual value behind an interface is not a pointer (say, an integer).

Comment: The `v  = v.Elem()` statement is only executed when `v` is an interface.  The statement will not panic.

Comment: Note that  `v.Elem()` on an interface returns the value that `v` contains.  If the interface contains an integer, then `v.Elem()` returns the integer value. I updated second example to include an interface containing an integer.